# I'm getting the insufficientFilePermissions error while trying to loop through all of my files in Google Drive

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth

Below is the code that I'm running to loop through my files:

```
files = service.files().list(fields='files(id)').execute().get('files', [])
    for file in files:
        perms = service.permissions().list(fileId=file['id']).execute()
        print(perms)
```

I'm getting the following error:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting [https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[fileid]/permissions?alt=json](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%5Bfileid%5D/permissions?alt=json) returned "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientFilePermissions', 'message': 'The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.'}]">

Below is the following scope of my credential file:

```
SCOPES = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly'
    ]
```

When I visit the link, [https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[fileid]/permissions?alt=json](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%5Bfileid%5D/permissions?alt=json), I see the following:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

To troubleshoot, I entered the following code in my loop:

```
files = service.files().list(fields='files(id)').execute().get('files', [])
    for file in files:
        r = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/file['id']/permissions?alt=json').json()
        if bool("error" not in in r):
                perms = service.permissions().list(fileId=file['id']).execute()
                print(perms)
```

When I executed the above code, apparently the error comes up for all the files.

I recreated the token file the last time I executed my code, so it is recent. I don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: Only the owner of a file can see the permissions i beleave.

Comment: @DaImTo But I am the owner of most of the files in my Google Drive, so I should be able to see the permissions of at least some them. None of them are showing in my debugging code.

Comment: Most of them not all of them figure out which file is giving you the error and see if you are the owner its a place to start at any rate.   beyond that edit your question and show how you are creating service

Comment: One of the files in my Drive that I know for sure that I am the owner of, I plugged its file ID into the URL that's in the error message (https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[file ID]/permissions?alt=json) and I'm getting this error in the JSON code: ```{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}```

Comment: If your not sending an authorization header then theres something wrong with service. the service object should be ensuring that a authorization header is set. Edit your code and add your authorizaton code

Comment: OK, I think I got it to work now. I inserted the useDomainAdminAccess parameter in the code, like so: service.permissions().list(fileId=file['id'], useDomainAdminAccess=True).execute(). I still hit a roadblock and got this error message from one of the JSON files that my code looped through: "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup." So, maybe it'll work tomorrow. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Your still not sending the authorization with your request.  Please edit your question and show me how you are creating service.  I need to see how you are creating service.